# Monitor a log file in real time, and do something. How?

Tags: ssh, monitoring, logfiles

I want to monitor a log file (omxd log file) in real time, and execute some commands when some sentences appear in the log.

I searched this site (and many other sites) and these are what I tried:

```
tail -f /var/log/omxlog | awk '/player_new/ { "echo hello" }'
```

or

```
stdbuf -o0 tail -F /var/log/omxlog | awk '/player_new/ { "echo hello" }'
```

But they don't work. Whenever I run these commands, it begins to wait, but although I'm sure the log file changes, it doesn't print hello; actually it doesn't do anything. Just waiting :D

Maybe the problem is that I'm accessing the RPi via SSH. I don't know.

So, what should I do!?

(System: Raspberry Pi. OS: Minibian)

Comment: you can do that using python script like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419888/reading-from-a-frequently-updated-file)

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `watch` command. [Click here for man page.](https://linux.die.net/man/1/watch)
Maybe something like:

`watch tail /var/log/omxlog | awk '/player_new/ { "echo hello" }'`

`watch` runs command (in your case `tail`) repeatedly and outputs to terminal. By adding pipe (`|`) the output is redirected to the `awk` command.